# Using the 'ed' editor, how can I print the first 20 matching lines?

Tags: regex

Given a file of humongous size, I can edit with ed, then issue the following command.

```
g/real/p
```

Which will print out all lines containing 'real'.

What I want to do is print the first 20.

I know sed, grep, head, etc. But I want to improve my ed skills.

Comment: I don't know `ed`, but `| head -n20`?

Comment: Hi, trying to find solution only using ed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify ranges before your commands in the form `from,to`.

```
1,4p
```

would print lines 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
ed -s infile <<IN
v/PATTERN/d               # delete all lines NOT matching PATTERN
,w !head -n20             # pass the addressed lines as input to shell command
u                         # undo deletion: not needed if you don't save changes
q                         # quit editor
IN
```